# Create conditional probabilities in pandas from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have probabilities in a pandas dataframe df (from first July 2011 up to 31th July 2011 in 15-min. periods).
Here is a excerpt:

```
         Date_Time      prob
0  2011-07-01 00:00:00  0.0112
1  2011-07-01 00:15:00  0.0224
2  2011-07-01 00:30:00  0.0112
3  2011-07-01 00:45:00  0.0896
4  2011-07-01 01:00:00  0.0112
5  2011-07-01 01:15:00  0.0112
6  2011-07-01 01:30:00  0.0336
7  2011-07-01 01:45:00  0.1081
8  2011-07-01 02:00:00  0.0112
```

I want to calculate the conditional probabilities (probability of A given B -> P(A|B))of one 15-min.-period an her four(!) forerunner. And this for every row (period).
That means (I used the index to name the rows here):

P(4|0), P(4|1), P(4|2), P(4|3)

P(5|1), P(5|2), P(5|3), P(5|4)

and so on.

The formula is: P(A|B) = P(A and B) / P(B), also (P(A)*P(B)/P(B))

Sorry, but I have no idea how I can do that. Maybe there is a useful pandas function, which I could fit, but I did not find something.

Comment: If `P(A|B) = P(A)*P(B)/P(B)`, then `A` and `B` are independent and `P(A|B) = P(A)`. So there is no calculation necessary...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`shift()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to calculate all these probabilities

```
>>> for i in range(1,5):
...     probB = df.shift(i)['prob']
...     probA = df['prob']
...     df['prob -' + str(i)] = (probA * probB) / probB
... 
>>> df
             Date_Time    prob  prob -1  prob -2  prob -3  prob -4
0 2011-07-01  00:00:00  0.0112      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1 2011-07-01  00:15:00  0.0224   0.0224      NaN      NaN      NaN
2 2011-07-01  00:30:00  0.0112   0.0112   0.0112      NaN      NaN
3 2011-07-01  00:45:00  0.0896   0.0896   0.0896   0.0896      NaN
4 2011-07-01  01:00:00  0.0112   0.0112   0.0112   0.0112   0.0112
5 2011-07-01  01:15:00  0.0112   0.0112   0.0112   0.0112   0.0112
6 2011-07-01  01:30:00  0.0336   0.0336   0.0336   0.0336   0.0336
7 2011-07-01  01:45:00  0.1081   0.1081   0.1081   0.1081   0.1081
8 2011-07-01  02:00:00  0.0112   0.0112   0.0112   0.0112   0.0112
```

Comment: Sorry I get: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index` What`s going wrong?

Comment: @EP1986 could you reproduce the error with small example dataset and post it here?